# Is it possible to move a GoogleMap object from one activity to another?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, android-fragments

So in my main activity I have instantiated a GoogleMap object.

On button click, in my next Acivity, I also have a GoogleMap object.

I want to know if it's possible to use the same object and not have to create a new GoogleMap object and do the appropriate set-up again.

Basically I don't want to do the same thing twice in two different activities and take the performance hit.

I know it's possible to move data via intents, extras, bundles etc.  but I can't find information regarding GoogleMaps or passing actual non-stringified objects.

Cheers.

Comment: Of course you can but need map in xml

Comment: You can serialize a map object?

Comment: yes you can do it as well. You can do anything that you can do to a general object

Comment: Which means I can JSONify it too then, right?

Comment: Yep... But remember the answer from Rod_Algonquin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you can pass the object to another activity, you need to have another instance of `map xml` in your second activity which will have a reference to **google map object**. Another solution is to have a static object of map which is not a good practice and I wont recommend it.

Comment: Of course, but at least my GoogleMap object will have all of the information I have previously supplied and it's just a case of assignment rather than going through the setup process again, no?

Comment: @SparkyRobinson yes you will have the information, but remember serializing that object or using parcelable will take a lot of time because you need to make sure that each variable are saved and restored on the next activity.

Comment: Ah, so maybe I'm better abstracting the map functionality out into its own class and just reapplying my set up process across various activities?

Comment: @SparkyRobinson If you just want to pass the information in the google map then just make a class that have all the informations and pass it as parcelable, so in the next activity it will read that information and you dont need to pass the map object itself but just its information that youve made.

Comment: Cheers Rod, appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can avoid all the hassle of serializing the object using https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Using EventBus you should be able to do something like:

```
Activity A {
    GoogleMap mMap;
    ...
    // just before moving to next Activity
    EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(map);
}

Activity B {
    GoogleMap mMap;

    void onCreate() {
        mMap = EventBus.getDefault().getStickyEvent(GoogleMap.class);
    }
}
```

Not only is it simpler, it actually outperforms any other alternatives such as parcelable etc.

I must admit that I do not have had the need of reusing GoogleMap across Activities, but I have successfully reused between orientation changes to avoid having to reload all my markers, setting target location, zoom level and so on.