# GoogleMap Fragment returning null object

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-play-services

I want to have a separate class from MainActivity for initializing map and have static method for initializing so it remains same across project and any class can use this googlemap object returning from class, I wrote a separate class

```
public class MapFragment extends AppCompatActivity{

public static SupportMapFragment mapFrag;

public static SupportMapFragment GetMapObj() {
   mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) new MainActivity().
   getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_map);
}
```

And in MainActivity using it like this

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = MapFragment.GetMapObj();
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

I have 2 xml 1 for the class above and 1 for mainActivity I dnt know where should I put my

```
 <fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/frag_map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    tools:context="com.example.sarahn.clientapimap.MainActivity"
    />
```

And having said all this my application crashing on null pointer exception that attempt to invoke getAsncMap on null object reference

}

Comment: Have you considered using onSaveInstanceState function to store map state status?

Comment: I want to have clean code and my MainActivity should exclude all this thing I just want to have object in MainActivity and calling getAsync on it

Comment: Never create an activity instance with `new`.  It will be uninitialized and useless.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede could you explain your point?

Comment: @blackHawk Using `new` will create a new Activity object for you, but it's essentially dead and unusable. You have to use `startActivity` and follow through the activity lifecycle to have a live Activity object.

Comment: When the Android framework creates an activity, it injects a `Context` into it and calls its initialization lifecycle methods.  Without all that initialization, methods like `getSupportFragmentManager` simply won't work.

Comment: So whats your opinion what should be done

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `NullPointerException` as your `mapFragment` is not initialized properly.

Initialize the `SupportMapFragment` in your `MainActivity` instead.

in `main_activity_xml`:

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Now in your `MainActivity`

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{


  SupportMapFragment smp;
  GoogleMap mMap;

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_xml);
        smp = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        smp.getMapAsync(this);
        }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        mMap = map;
        //map initialized
    }
}
```

Comment: but as i stated earlier that i want to have these things inside another class rather than in MainActivity, i just want to call getMapAsync on returned object in MainActivity

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517406/is-it-possible-to-move-a-googlemap-object-from-one-activity-to-another   static object of map which is not a good practice

Comment: Why can't i do, what i want to do

Comment: First of all `MapFragment.GetMapObj()`..will never return a valid object..cause layout not inflated yet..see this: http://android.tutorialhorizon.com/static-fragments-declare-the-fragment-as-a-element-inside-the-activitys-layout-file/

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you want your activity do something when the user does something in the map.

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener{

    private MapFragment mapFragment;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private OnMapListener onMapListener;

    public static YourFragment newInstance(){
        return new YourFragment();
    }

    @Override public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            this.onMapListener = (OnMapListener)context;
        }
        catch (final ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement OnMapListener");
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);

        mapFragment = (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id. frag_map); 
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this); //Its async, It could last a little bit and 
        //that is the reason why you are getting NULL,
        // to work Asynchronously you should implement the Callback 'OnMapReadyCallback'.

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) { 
        mMap = googleMap; 
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
        onMapListener.onMapClick(latLng);
    }

    @Override public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        onMapListener.onMarkerClick(marker);
    }

    public interface OnMapListener{
        void onMapClick(LatLng latLng);
        void onMarkerClick(Marker marker);
    }
}


public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapListener {

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...
        YourFragment newFragment = YourFragment.newInstance();
        ...
    }

    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng){
    //do something on your activity
    }
    public void onMarkerClick(Marker marker){
    //do something on your activity
    }          
}
```

Comment: I have implemented like, but as i stated earlier that i want to have these things inside another class rather than in MainActivity, i just want to call getMapAsync on returned object in MainActivity

Comment: I think you should reuse the GoogleMap's object, not SupportMapFragment's object but I have a question, do you want to reuse that object in several activities or just one?

Comment: I just want to have clean code so that my MainActivity should exclude all this and leverage initialization to other class

Comment: I update my answer dude, tell me if you want something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend `SupportMapFragment` and initialize the map in the fragment's own `onCreate` method. This avoids cluttering your activity with code that logically belongs to the fragment.

```
public class MyMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap map) {
                // configure the map here
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then put it in your activity XML just like you would an ordinary `SupportMapFragment`.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.myapp.MyMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

If you still need to access the fragment from your activity, you'd call `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)`. But since the fragment configures the map, the activity may no longer need to access it. An activity that uses fragments is often little more than `onCreate` calling `setContentView`.

Comment: Will it be separated from MainActivity and how can I use it in MainActivity?

Comment: @blackHawk It would be in your own custom fragment class, as shown.  I'm not sure what else you mean by separated.  The activity could get a reference to the fragment via `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)`.  What does the activity want to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to create an new context rather than having the OS do it. You have to use `startActivity` on an existing context to create a new activity.

As for how you want to get your map object, here is an example:

```
public class MapFragment extends AppCompatActivity{

    public static SupportMapFragment mapFrag;

    public static SupportMapFragment GetMapObj(FragmentActivity activity) {
       mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) activity.
         getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_map);
    }
}
```

And in your activity, just call this:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = MapFragment.GetMapObj(this);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Comment: Also, keep in mind this assumes that you have already attached the fragment to this activity's fragment manager.

Comment: please update your answer, about attaching fragment to activity fragment

Comment: Not sure if static method should be recommended

Comment: Honestly, this is a patch to @blackHawk code, not a solution. The proper solution is one of the 3 other answers.